# JQuery key is undefined in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Wanting to be able to have multiple people take a survey then refresh etc. Need multiple people to be able to store a survey based on their name so each survey result is not overwritten when re-submitted. Trying to get the keys stored for each text box output 'person'.'name' = value. instead im getting a undefined.name = value

```
<p>
<label>Name:</label> <input name="MainName" type="text"/>
</p>

$('form').submit(function() {
 var person = $("#MainName").val();
 $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
   var value = $(this).val(),
       name = $(this).attr('name');
       localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;

     console.log('stored key: '+name+' stored value: '+value);
});   
});
```

If the problem doesnt show above here is the whole: http://jsfiddle.net/5sG8v/

Comment: MainName is name of the input element not and ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` returned because you're trying to reference an ID that does not exist: `MainName` is the `name` of your input field, not the `id.` Give it an ID of `MainName`, or whatever tickles your fancy:

```
<label>Name:</label> <input id="MainName" name="MainName" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Of course, I'm still a newbie but thanks for the help! seemed to do the trick!

Comment: how do you go about using 2 ids? var person = $("#firstname",#"lastname") etc

Comment: That would give you an array of results, so you'd have to pick out which one you want. What is your goal in doing this? There is likely a better alternative. If you simply want to concatenate strings, the cleanest way is to use multiple selectors: `var person = $('#firstname').val() + " " + $('#lastname').val();`

Comment: @Desertlvy Simple local storage/retrieval. No analytics off the data or anything. That works perfect for what I'm trying to do, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `#` is for selecting elements with a given `id` attribute. Your `input` doesn't have an `id`.

You could give the element an `id`, or select based on the `name` attribute:

```
$('input[name="MainName"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `$("#MainName").val();` to get the value of element having ID `MainName`.
 `#` is used to access element with IDs but you haven't defined that ID in html.

So define the ID attribute of the textbox like this :

```
<label>Name:</label> <input id="MainName" name="MainName" type="text"/>
```